# Oracle APEX error ORA-06502 on Data Loading Wizard

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

I'm developing an Oracle APEX application and I generated a Data Loading Wizard, but when I try to use it with a file the following error happens:

```
Technical Info (only visible for developers)

is_internal_error: false
ora_sqlcode: -6502
ora_sqlerrm: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: error : character string buffer too small numérico o de valor
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_PROCESS
component.id: 19295165393405241
component.name: Parse Uploaded Data
error_backtrace: 
ORA-06512: en "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_COLLECTION", línea 3517
ORA-06512: en "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_DATA_UPLOAD", línea 876
ORA-06512: en "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", línea 1003
ORA-06512: en "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", línea 1208
ORA-06512: en "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", línea 2397
ORA-06512: en "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS", línea 191
```

I've tried to use the same Data Loader with the Copy-Paste option and it works (at least goes past the first page). Is there a way to check for more details about this error on the database? These messages are not really useful to me and I don't have DB admin access.

I'm using Oracle APEX 5.1 and Oracle 12c

Edit:

Example of a record:

```
"Month";"Type";"1234 1234567";"01/01/2017";"31/01/2017";"10.0212";;"Company Name";"12345678 12312345";"01/01/2017";"ABC";"ALPHANUEMRCAL123";"USA";"USA";"DESCRIPTION MAX 150 CHAR";"1";"12,345.67";"1234";"12,345.67";"12345678";"I1";;"Text";;;"2017";;"ABCDE";1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you set wrong Separator. If you upload xlsx file try first to convert it to csv and set separator to ';'. Please post more info about file structure and type.

Comment: I have already converted it to CSV, with `"` delimiters and `;` separators before uploading it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too. My problem was, that I forgot to check out in the first page the 'First Row has Column Names' option, and I only had the datas.

In your case maybe the errors with the datas, you have to add the rows with separated by '/n' or enter if it's a row text.
Also, check double the separator character, because it's bydefault is the '/t' not the ';'in the copy-paste section.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your observations, both were useful. The problem was that the file was being generated with special characters which weren't recognized in Oracle (different charset than the one I use). I had to open the file in Notepad++ and view all characters to view this.